# Getting one dataframe by mutiliplying columns of one dataframe with rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pca

I have two dataframes, of shape m*5 and 5*n. The column names of the 1st dataframe with 5 columns is same as the index of the 2nd dataframe with 5 rows. I want to multiply each element of each row in the 1st dataframe with the 1st 2 columns of the 2nd dataframe with having corresponding row index in the 2nd dataframe. Please find below the dataframes for reference:

DataFrame 1:

```
                       %age_paid_0.0  %age_paid_0.1  %age_paid_0.2  %age_paid_0.3  \
account_angaza_id                                                               
AC005839                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005842                0.299221       0.299221       0.521691       0.521691   
AC005843                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005851                0.243604       0.310345       0.354839       0.354839   
AC005852                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005853                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005856                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005858                0.299221       0.377086       0.454950       0.532814   
AC005859                0.332592       0.432703       0.543938       0.650723   
AC005860                0.288098       0.365962       0.421580       0.532814   

                   %age_paid_0.4  %age_paid_0.5  
account_angaza_id                                
AC005839                0.610679       0.688543  
AC005842                0.521691       0.521691  
AC005843                0.610679       0.766407  
AC005851                0.510567       0.555061  
AC005852                0.610679       0.766407  
AC005853                0.610679       0.688543  
AC005856                0.610679       0.766407  
AC005858                0.543938       0.588432  
AC005859                0.650723       0.739711  
AC005860                0.532814       0.632925
```

Dataframe 2:

```
                      0         1
%age_paid_0.0  0.369886  0.673442
%age_paid_0.1  0.409603  0.374386
%age_paid_0.2  0.425269  0.058336
%age_paid_0.3  0.425229 -0.191075
%age_paid_0.4  0.415484 -0.369895
%age_paid_0.5  0.401384 -0.479141
```

Expected dataframe:

```
                   0         1
  AC005839     1.xxxxxx  2.xxxxxx
  AC005840     xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx
  AC005840     xxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxx
```

The formula is

```
dataframe3.loc['AC005839',0] = dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.1]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.1,0]+dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.2]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.2,0]+...+dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.5]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.5,0]
dataframe3.loc['AC005839',1] = dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.1]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.1,1]+dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.2]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.2,1]+...+dataframe1.loc['AC005839',%age_paid_0.5]*dataframe2.loc[%age_paid_0.5,1]
```

Any kind of help will be really appreciated. Basically I am trying to convert a variables into the same plane as the principle components are. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like dot product to me. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dot product. Since your index/column labels match, all you need is:

```
df1.dot(df2)
```